# How to organize internal code if exported items from modules exposes them?

Tags: rust, module, interface, implementation

I am working on a Rust module that has a small external interface, but its internal implementation is large and complex.

Is there a sane way to avoid having a huge file with all the code for the module while still exposing a small interface to external module consumers?

AFAIK, Rust does not allow you to use several files for the same module, as for instance Go allows for package directories. It does not matter that the Rust module is defined in a directory, it still expects one single file.

That way, to split code up you are forced to use sub-modules for sub-types or implementation details that you would want to split apart. I understand that should not matter much for compiled code,  all overhead of the module organization is removed.

But there is a design problem, if I split things up in modules, those will need to export things so that I can used them from my other modules... but then those "exported internals" can ALSO be used by external consumers, right? Is there a way to avoid exposing those internal interfaces?

Comment: You can have internal and external modules, and export the external module under the crate root while having the external using the internal modules. I like this solution because it makes the API boundary explicit and easy to follow.

Comment: Use a directory for your module. In this directory you'll have `mod.rs`, where you'll `pub use` all the things you want the external consumers to use. The files inside the directory though should be able to use each other with `use super::something`, without `pub use super::something` required

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But there is a design problem, if I split things up in modules, those will need to export things so that I can used them from my other modules... but then those "exported internals" can ALSO be used by external consumers, right?

No, they can not.

Making a symbol public in a sub-module only makes it available to its immediate parent. That parent module would then have to *re-export* that symbol via `pub use` for the visibility to "bubble up".

```rust
mod foo {
    mod bar {
        pub fn visible_in_foo() {}
        pub fn visible_in_root() {}
        fn private() {}
    }
    
    // Re-export to make visible at the next outer level
    pub use bar::visible_in_root;

    pub fn foo() {
        // We are in the immediate parent, so both `pub` functions are visible
        bar::visible_in_foo();
        bar::visible_in_root();
        // bar::private(); - Won't compile
    }
}

// Make it public to consumers of the library, aka. external API
pub use foo::foo;

fn main() {
    // Notice that it's just `foo`. Not `foo::bar` or `bar`.
    // Re-exporting makes the symbol a part of module `foo`.
    foo::visible_in_root();

    // foo::visible_in_foo(); - Won't compile

    // `foo::foo` does have access to the inner module, though,
    // so we can call `foo::bar::visible_in_foo` indirectly here.
    foo::foo();
}
```

Additionally, you can mark symbols as `pub(crate)`, which works like `pub`, except it prevents the symbol from becoming public outside the crate, even if it were re-exported by all of its parent modules.

Further reading:

- [The Rust Programming Language - Defining Modules to Control Scope and Privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html)
- [The Rust Reference - Visibility and Privacy](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/visibility-and-privacy.html?highlight=pub#visibility-and-privacy)

Comment: Thanks! Then I can split internal details in sub-modules without much concern, expect maybe that it requires more ceremony than just using another file in the same directory, for comparison.